# freeze and thaw tmux and/or terminal sessions?

Tags: terminal, session, tmux

I would like to be able to freeze and thaw tmux sessions. That is, to take a complex set of session state, persist it, and bring it back from some persistent store later. Essentially, git stash for terminal session state. Does anybody know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CryoPID](https://github.com/maaziz/cryopid) is close to being able to do this, I'm not aware of any others.

Answer (score 0):

[`tmux`-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) is useful here. It won't capture all the state you might be interested in but it does things such as pane layouts and contents and vim sessions.